# What is the tax-free amount of gas I can bring to Lithuania from Kaliningrad?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, driving, road-trips, eu, lithuania

I am planning a trip from Kaliningrad to Tallinn. Since gasoline in Russia is cheaper than in Lithuania, it is useful to fill up a canister and bring it across the border to the Schengen zone.

What is the upper limit for tax-free import of gasoline (for a car) in a portable container to Lithuania from outside of the EU? For Estonia for example it is [10 liters](http://www.emta.ee/eng/customs-regulations-travellers-arriving-estonia-non-community-countries) but I can't seem to find a similar source for Lithuania ([this resource](https://lithuania.visahq.com/customs/) for example does not list fuel).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limits are exactly the same for all EU countries, since they're in a single market and cannot set their own rules when it comes to imports from non-EU countries. Therefore for Lithuania (and all other EU members) [the limit is as following](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/individuals/travelling/entering-eu_en):

> - In any means of motor transport, the fuel contained in the standard    tank; and
> - a quantity of fuel not exceeding **10 litres** contained in a portable    container.

Note that this only applies to non-commerical imports, which means you're not allowed to resell this fuel after crossing the border.